# Are there physical interpretations of fractional order integrals and derivatives?

Tags: integration, derivatives, mathematical-modeling, fractional-calculus

Integral and differential calculus restricted to integer order operations of integration and differentiation have solid, definite connections with models of the physical world such as figuring areas, volumes, rates of change, etc.

But what of the fractional calculus?

Are there any physical interpretations that come from fractional order derivatives and integrals?

Comment: There are some papers on this exact title

Comment: Among physical phenomena, **anomalous decay** is the one that is most likely connected with fractional derivatives.

Comment: @polfosol but anomalous decay is better modeled by having a time constant that depends on one of the system states. That's called a Linear Parameter Varying (LPV) system. An example is pressure decay of gas in a closed container through an orifice. The nonlinear model is physically driven in the structure. The linear decay model can be realized by an integrator in negative feedback with the reciprocal of the time constant. So you are saying if I make this integrator fractional I have a better physical interpretation?

Comment: @polfosol ... I don't believe so. How does a fractional order integrator behave, and is there anything in the real world that behaves in a similar way? Given a 2D function, the integral the function is the *area* under that function. So what does a fractional order integration yield?

Comment: @polfosol you mention 'papers'. Do you recall of any specific titles?

Comment: [This](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110241.pdf) and [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016003297000483) are the ones that I have read a while ago (my PhD was about controlling nonlinear fractional systems). For my argument about anomalous decay, please refer to (for example:) [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.6869.pdf) and [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3780456)...

Comment: @Bye_World: It is unwise to edit "dormant" questions if they do not contain major errors; removing a harmless tag cannot justify an edit. In this precise case, though, your edit was even wrong: the tag "mathematical-physics" fitted the subject of the question very well. Even though I'm tempted to, I shall not roll back to the previous version, but maybe you should be more parcimonious with this type of interventions on other people's posts.

Comment: @AlexM. (physics) might work, but this is too broad to be from the field of mathematical physics.  I think (mathematical-modelling) is the relevant tag (which it's already tagged with).  And I've noticed that the (mathematical-physics) tag has been wildly misused.  So I've been slowly removing it from old posts where it's not relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The physical interpretation of the fractional order derivative may best be described by the Grunwald-Letnikov definition. Without loss of generality, consider the autonomous dynamical system:
$$\dot{x}=f(x)$$
We can model this dynamical system in discrete-time. Like this:
$$\frac{x(t)-x(t-\delta)}{\delta}\approx f\left(x(t-\delta)\right)$$
Or in traditional form, by replacing $t-\delta$ with $k$:
$$x(k+1)=F(x(k))$$
What does the above equation say? The evident fact about this dynamical model is, the future state of the system is only a function of the ***current*** state.

Now think about how do we generalize the definition of the derivative. We know that:
$$\mathcal D^1 x(t)= x'(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{x(t)-x(t-h)}{h}}$$
By induction and using the Leibniz rule:
$$\mathcal D^n x(t)= x^{(n)}(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{1}{h^n}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^i \binom{n}{i} x(t-ih)}$$
This definition is generalized by Grunwald-Letnikov for fractional derivatives, replacing $n$ by $\alpha\in\mathbb R_+$ and defining:
$$\binom{\alpha}{i}=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha-i+1)\text{ }i!}$$
Back to the story, now consider the fractional-order system:
$$\mathcal D^{\alpha} x(t)=f(x)$$
We can say that:
$${\frac{1}{\delta^{\alpha}}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^i \binom{\alpha}{i}x(t-i\delta)}\approx f\left(x(t-\delta)\right)$$
Hence
$$x(t)=\delta^{\alpha}f\left(x(t-\delta)\right)+\alpha x(t-\delta)- \sum_{i=2}^{\infty}(-1)^i \binom{\alpha}{i}x(t-i\delta)$$
Similar to the integer-order system, one can convert the above equation to a standard form like:
$$x(k+1)=F(x(k),\alpha)+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^i \binom{\alpha}{i+1} x(k-i)$$
Note the difference of the above equation with the integer-order model. As you see, the next state of the system is *not only* a function of the current state, but also a function of all previous states (some call it the ***memory*** of the system). Since $\binom{\alpha}{i+1}$ gets smaller as $i$ increases, the effect of this memory fades in time.

**tl,dr**

According to the Grunwald-Letnikov definition, one may conclude that those systems with effective memories can be better modeled by fractional derivatives. There are already tons of papers with this approach in various areas such as visco-elasticity, diffusion, fluid dynamics, etc. and the number is growing fast.

Comment: I follow your argument but have an issue with the statement "better modeled by fractional derivatives". RE:my example of the pressure  vessel with an orifice and initial pressure. One can synthesize a LPV structure with a normal integrator that not only well models the behavior, but has a physical basis to begin with. It *also* has memory. At best a fractional order model would just be a black box fit with no physical basis motivating the model structure from the start. But I'll concede I could be wrong. I still need to look at the references you mentioned in the comments above. Thanks.