# Is there a rigorous proof for $dt^\alpha =0$ for $\alpha >1$?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes

If $(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion, we say formally that $dB_t=(dt)^{1/2}$. And then we use the formal notation $dt\cdot dB_t=dt\cdot dt=0$ and $dB_t\cdot dB_t=dt$.

Q1) Is there a rigorous reason for that or is it only a convention ? In general, if $\alpha >1$, why (dt)^\alpha =0$ ? Can we prove this ?

Q2) I know that the fact that $(B_t)$ has no bounded variation, but only quadratic variation gives us that $dB_t=(dt)^{1/2}$. But how can we justify this fact rigorously ?

---

This question is quite correlated to my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130184/understanding-better-quadratic-variation-and-fractional-derivative). But since the question is not the same, I prefered to open a new question.

Comment: I think you should apply Ito's Formula to find out :)

Comment: A low-tech answer for Q1 would be that, for $\alpha > 1$, $$\lim_{\|P\|\to0}\sum_{\xi_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]\in P} f(\xi_i) (x_i - x_{i-1})^{\alpha} \to 0$$ for any continuous function $f$ on $[a, b]$ and along partitions $P$ of $[a, b]$ whose mesh sizes go to $0$.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: For me, $df$ refer to the linear approximation of $f$. In other word, $d_xf=K(x)dt$ would be the linear approximation of $f$ arround $x$. In particular, if $\alpha >1$, then $f(x+dt)=f(x)+d_xf+o(dt)+J(x)dt^\alpha =f(x)+d_xf+o(dt).$

Comment: @saz: the link doesn't work...

Comment: For the very first part of your first question you might want to take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81865/36150) (and the linked questions as well).